Failure to generate "allure-report" when running "allure generate --single-file allure-results"
I added the latest version for allure-testng (2.27) with the following dependency to my pom.xml file. I also have the same version installed on my local to be able to use the terminal.
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.27.0</version>
</dependency>

When I run my test cases with the testng.xml I prepared, the allure-results folder is created and I can also serve and view this report with "allure serve".
But what I need is to prepare it as a single html because I want to share it with my teammates (I haven't implemented alternatives like "netlify" for security reasons).
When I use the command "allure generate --single-file allure-results --clean" I return "Report successfully generated to allure-report" but there is no allure-report file at all.
Thank you for all the answers and the exchange of ideas.

The Allure report is generated in the allure-report/index.html file by default using single-file mode.
